# What are llvm_pipe threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, rust, process, llvm

I'm writing a Rust app that uses a lot of threads. I noticed the CPU usage was high so I did `top` and then hit `H` to see the threads:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                
         
 247759 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 R  32.2   1.0   0:02.98 my_app           
 247785 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  22.9   1.0   0:01.89 llvmpipe-0             
 247786 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  21.9   1.0   0:01.71 llvmpipe-1             
 247792 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  20.9   1.0   0:01.83 llvmpipe-7             
 247789 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  20.3   1.0   0:01.60 llvmpipe-4             
 247790 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  20.3   1.0   0:01.64 llvmpipe-5             
 247787 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  19.9   1.0   0:01.70 llvmpipe-2             
 247788 root      20   0 3491496 104400  64676 S  19.9   1.0   0:01.61 llvmpipe-3
```

What are these  `llvmpipe-n` threads? Why `my_app` launches them? Are them even from `my_app` for sure?

Comment: Note that the question may be better suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: What kind of application? What libraries are you using? Quick googling leads to https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/llvmpipe.html

Comment: @HHK I'm using `glium`, which is a rust crate that does OpenGL rendering. Also, I'm inside a VM. Do you think the llvm pipe is from glium or from the VM? I don't see why to virtualize vertex processing outside the VM so I'd guess is the VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HHK links to, the `llvmpipe` threads are from your OpenGL driver, which is Mesa.

You said you are running this in a VM. VMs usually don't virtualize GPU hardware, so the Mesa OpenGL driver is doing sofware rendering. To achieve better performance, Mesa spawns threads to do parallel computations on the CPU.